# Oracle: max value column alphanumeric

Tags: sql, oracle, max, alphanumeric

The problem I can not get the latest code. I need it to generate the next.

Example:

```
 Last:
 D11.0602.166

 Next:
 D11.0603.166
```

**I've tried:**

```
 MAX
 TRANSLATE
 CONVERT
 MID
 VAL
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  The `max()` function should do what you want.

Comment: Gordon's correct: `MAX` should find the latest. Are you asking more about what to do with the `MAX` value once you find it? If so, could you post a description of your numbering scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a "smart key" - one attribute comprising three elements.  Smart keys are dumb, because they're a pain in tha neck to work with.

So the correct solution will be to split that attribute into three separate attributes and make it a composite key instead.

In the meantime you could use reguklar expressions to fin dthe highest value of the middle component...

```
select max(regexp_replace(dumb_key
               , '([A-Z][0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})\..([0-9]{3})'
               , '\2'))
from your_table
/
```

No doubt there are all sorts of other complexities you haven't explained, which means this probably isn't the compleat solution.  But it should be a starter for ten.